# Local assumptions in "state" mode

Tags: isabelle, isar

Frequently, when proving a statement in "prove" mode, I find myself in need of some intermediate statements that are not yet stated nor proved. To state them, I usually make use of the `subgoal` command, followed by `proof-` to change to "state" mode. In the process, however, all of the local assumptions are removed. A typical example could look like this

```
lemma "0 < n ⟷ ((2::nat)^n < 3^n)"
  apply(auto)
  subgoal
  proof-
    have "0<n" sorry (* here I would like to refer to the assumption from the subgoal *)
    then show ?thesis sorry
  qed
  subgoal sorry
  done
```

I am aware that I could state the assumptions using `assume` explicitly. However, this becomes quickly rather tedious when multiple assumptions are involved. Is there an easier way to simply refer to all of the assumptions? Alternatively, is there a good way to implement statements with short proofs directly in "prove" mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the syntax `subgoal premises prems` to bind the premises of the subgoal to the name `prems` (or any other name – but `prems` is a sensible default):

```
lemma "0 < n ⟷ ((2::nat)^n < 3^n)"
  apply(auto)
  subgoal premises prems
  proof -
    thm prems
```

There is also a method called `goal_cases` that automatically gives names to all the current subgoals – I find it very useful. If `subgoal premises` did not exist, you could do this instead:

```
lemma "0 < n ⟷ ((2::nat)^n < 3^n)"
  apply(auto)
  subgoal
  proof goal_cases
    case 1
```

By the way, looking at your example, it is considered a bad idea to do anything after `auto` that depends on the exact form of the proof state, such as `metis` calls or Isar proofs. `auto` is fairly brutal and might behave differently in the next Isabelle release so that such proofs break. I recommend doing a nice structured Isar proof here.

Also note that your theorem is a direct consequence of `power_strict_mono` and `power_less_imp_less_base` and can be proven in a single line:

```
lemma "0 < n ⟷ ((2::nat)^n < 3^n)"
  by (auto intro: Nat.gr0I power_strict_mono)`
```

Comment: On the "apply auto proof -": https://proofcraft.org/blog/isabelle-style.html is a good reference on good proofs style.